# this.refs is undefined for shallow tests using enzyme on React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component which has 2 input text fields.

In the `componentDidMount()` method I am calling             `this.refs.password.focus();`

There is some amount of tricky business logic sitting inside my `componentDidMount` but while doing a shallow unit test on `componentDidMount`, I get error

> cannot access password of undefined

I checked the instance of the shallow component and see that `this.refs` is ***undefined***.
My question is how can we set this through tests?

Shallow has a second parameter which we can pass called as the context where we can set the context for unit testing but it seems to be doing nothing.

Any help around this area would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest approach for this problem would be to set the `refs` through the instance.

```
const component = shallow(<Component />)
const instance = component.instance()

instance.refs = {
  password: {
    getRenderedComponent: jest.fn(() => ({
      focus: jest.fn
    }))
  }
}
```

Comment: What if the ref is used during component mounting? In my case, my test fails on line 1 when I do the initial shallow render. I don't even get a chance to mock the refs...

Comment: @MegaMatt In that case you can pass on a context to the shallow as a parameter. Check the documentation : https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md , you could pass the context.refs while shallow mounting the component.

Comment: Hi @Bajju, can you please add an example of passing refs through context. I have a table element, and on `CDM` lifecycle method it calculates the height. How to pass the refs in this case!

Comment: @DebajitMajumder
As you want to test CDM , you need to have 
`instance = shallow(<Component {...props} />, { disableLifecycleMethods: true })` and then add the mock refs
 instance.refs = {
                    table: {
                        calculateHeight: mockCalculateHeight,
                    },
                };

Then call the CDM() and then verify the function.

Comment: instance.refs is deprecated unfortunately

Answer (score 4):

`shallow` does not have a `ref` method. You need to use `mount` to test the rendering in its entirety.

References: 
API docs:
https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md
https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md

Issue:
https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/316