# test onChange event in enzyme and jest with refs

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am using `ref` to get the value of input box. I want to make a test case of search component where it can simulate the onChange event. If I running my `handleSearchChange` from test case. it is not able to resolve `ref`.

> Component

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { injectProps } from 'relpers';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


export class Search extends Component{

  state = {
    searchValue: ''
  }

  handleSearchChange = ()=>{
    const { handleInputChange } = this.props;
    let searchValue = this.search.value;
    this.setState({
      searchValue
    });
    //handleInputChange(searchValue);
  }

  render(){
    let { searchValue } = this.state;
    let { placeHolder } = this.props;
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          id={'searchInput'}
          placeholder={placeHolder}
          ref={input => this.search = input}
          value={searchValue}
          onChange={this.handleSearchChange}
        />
      </form>
    )
  }
}


Search.propTypes = {
  placeHolder: PropTypes.string,
  handleInputChange: PropTypes.func,
};

Search.defaultProps = {
  placeHolder: "Search for order..",
  handleInputChange:()=>{}
};
```

> Test case

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { Search } from './search';

describe('<Search /> component test cases', ()=>{
  it('check if search component render properly',()=>{
    const wrapper = shallow(<Search />);
    expect(wrapper.find('input')).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  it('checks if handleSearchChange method works correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Search />);
    const searchInput = wrapper.find("#searchInput");
    searchInput.value = "123456";
    searchInput.simulate('change');
    expect(wrapper.instance().state.searchValue).toEqual('123456');
  });
})
```

> Error
>   [image]

**Edited**

Checking ref with mount

```
it('checks if handleSearchChange method works correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Search />);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();

    const searchInput = wrapper.find("#searchInput");
    searchInput.value = "123456";
    searchInput.simulate('change');
    expect(wrapper.instance().state.searchValue).toEqual('123456');
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shallow` does not appear to support `refs` - it looks like you need to use `mount`

[mount docs](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/mount.html)

[another SO post about this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46482258/1265528)

Also, you really don't need to use `ref` at all in this situation. You can just use your `onChange` handler like so

```
handleSearchChange = (e) => {
  const { handleInputChange } = this.props;
  let searchValue = e.target.value;
  this.setState({searchValue});
  // whatever else you want to do
}
```

You'll just have to bind `this` somewhere, for example in your render method, something like.

`<input onChange={this.handleSearchChange.bind(this)} />`

Comment: I have seen this but in my case I am not using event to get the input value but ref instead

Comment: Ahh whoops, if you want `refs` you have to use `mount`

Comment: I am using mount now but still it is not working. I have edited my question

Comment: because you cannot set `.value` through wrapper. Do it through ref you have: `const searchInput = wrapper.instance().search; searchInput.value = '123456'; wrapper.find('#searchInput').simulate('change');`